# What is hashgacha pratis

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, creation

I always hear the term but I thought it meant hashgacha in everything that occurs. I did some research and found that hashgacha pratis refers to the animals and vegatation as opposed to just general hashgacha of the world, hashgacha klalis.
So what is hashgacha pratis, is it me and you or the rest of creation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_providence_in_Judaism#:~:text=Divine%20providence%20(Hebrew%3A%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%92%D7%97%D7%94%20%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%99%D7%AA,the%20tradition%20of%20Jewish%20mysticism.

Comment: This was hotly debated in medieval Jewish philosophy. Some of the books mentioned [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106278/what-is-a-summary-of-basic-jewish-metaphysics-or-theology/106284#106284) discuss the topic at length.

Comment: Different Rishonim used these terms slightly differently (R. Daniel Eidensohn has a good survey text to my memory). In the Rambam's system, to crudely reduce it to simplistic terms, השגחה כללית is the natural order (i.e. the systems by which the universe is governed) and השגחה פרטית is the individual providence that some righteous/intellectually-perfected individuals merit to have over them. The degree to which an individual is governed by השגחה פרטית corresponds to the extent of their individual perfection (those lacking in perfection are subject to השגחה כללית like the rest of creation).

Comment: There is a debate if hashgacha pratis applies to animals etc. Standard answer is no. The term really is meant to apply to people, as @Deuteronomy says.