# Do we believe in coincidences?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

How far should one take coincidences?
Should one go with the mehalech that everything is divine intervention and take it as a simaan? Or can one brush it off as simply a coincidence?
For example, if I was thinking of making a hypothetical business deal and then I see someone post a question on mi yodea of whether or not it's allowed to invest in a business owned by a rasha.

What should my course of action be towards my hypothetical business deal. Should I question my potential business partners integrity or ignore this seeming coincidence and go through with the deal?

This question is not about prophecy, it is addressing how deeply one should think of seeming happenstances occurring to him which may or may not be a siman min hashamayim.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronicity

Comment: The letters of Mikre (coincidence) also form Rak-Mei-Hashem ....

Comment: There seem to be 2 questions here, that probably should be separated out. One is answered here: [How do you know what God wants without prophets now to tell you?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37293/how-do-you-know-what-god-wants-without-prophets-now-to-tell-you). The other, about if everything is a coincidence, is related/dupe of [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/130065/what-is-hashgacha-pratis) or similar.

Comment: I don't see the relation @RabbiKaii

Comment: This is a great question. Within Orthodox Judaism there are the full range of views, from complete rationalist to the Baal Shem Tov's 'even a leaf falling when it does and how it does is a message'. Most of us fall somewhere in between. Email me if you'd like to discuss further (address is on my profile).